# How to convert char to int, and vice versa?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, integer

I would like to turn a `char` into an `int` without using output formats, and vice versa. How do I do that?

Comment: `(int)c` works quite well. `c - '0'` may work as well. Please, specify your problem a bit more. Give example of expected input and output.

Comment: Just cast the variable. char c; int i = 25; c= (char) i;

Comment: my_char = '10'    my_int = int(my_var);     my_str = str(my_int) ; If it not able to convert python raise  ValueError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a *single* digit character, like `'1'` or `'9'`?  Then you would do something like this:

```
char c = '5';      
int  x = c - '0';  // x == 5
```

Digit encodings are consecutive in all character character coding schemes (ASCII, EBCDIC, etc.), so subtracting the code for `'0'` gives you the right value.

Are you talking about converting the *character encoding* to an integer?  Then all you need to do is assign the character value to an `int`:

```
int x = '5'; // x contains the character encoding of '5' - in ASCII, 53
```

Are you talking about converting a character *string*, like `"12"` or `"42"`?  Then you would need to use one of the `sscanf`, `strtol`, or `atoi` library functions (or roll your own equivalent).  Given

```
char str[] = "123";
int x;
```

you would do

```
sscanf( str, "%d", &x );
```

or

```
x = atoi( str );
```

or

```
char *chk;
x = (int) strtol( str, &chk, 10 );
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  // str contained a non-numeric character, handle as appropriate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the ASCII value of a character

```
 char c1 = 'A';
 printf("%d",(int)c1);     //Prints ASCII value of character 'A' = (65)
```

the following piece of code also prints the ASCII value of a character

```
char c1 = 'A';
printf("%d ",c1);         //Prints ASCII value of character 'A' = (65)
```

If you want to print the value of a character

```
char c2 = '5';
int x = c2-'0';
printf("%d",x); //prints integer value of character '5'(5)
```